# TTFB different between 2 identical virtual hosts on same machine

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost

After almost 3 years of finding every answer on either StackOverflow or ServerFault, I'm finally stuck on one. I recently migrated our server from dedicated to VPS, and the problem now is that we have a production and development site on the same server (Apache2 - CentOS - and low traffic/load), setup via Virtual Hosts, however the TTFB for the production site is right around 8s on average, while development loads in about 1.3s. The sites are identical, same MySQL db, same everything.

I've fine-tuned all the httpd.conf settings, php.ini settings, etc., and no difference. I'm leaning toward the idea that it is a DNS resolution issue, but as our DNS is all located in the same place and points to the same IP, it seems unlikely. In addition, both the virtual servers have identical setups in httpd.conf, except obviously for the names.

Nothing exceptional in the logs, no errors in loading the site, just cannot account for the latency between the production (www.) and development (dev.) sites.

The httpd.conf Virtual Host bits are here: (multi-domain SSL Cert)

```
# www.sharegate.com Virtual Host ########
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /path/to/www.sharegate.com/
ServerName www.sharegate.com:443
ServerAdmin webmaster@sharegate.com

SSLEngine on
//SSL Settings here//

<Directory /path/to/www.sharegate.com>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  //php settings//
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase / 

//Rewrite Rules//

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# dev.sharegate.com Virtual Host ########
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /path/to/dev.sharegate.com/
ServerName dev.sharegate.com:443
ServerAdmin webmaster@sharegate.com

SSLEngine on
// SSL Settings here //

<Directory /path/to/dev.sharegate.com>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  //php settings//
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase / 

//Rewrite Rules//

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for any advice from anyone who may have experienced similar.